# Expressing "with a higher variance" as an adjective

Tags: american-english, north-american-english

Is it possible to express

> has a higher variance

in the sentence

> Dataset A has a higher variance than dataset B

as an adjective? Would

> Dataset A is more variable than dataset B

be the right choice?

Comment: Is more variative.

Comment: [A quick NGrams search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more+variable+than%2Cmore+variant+than%2C+higher+variance+than&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows that 'more variable' >> 'higher variance' > 'more variant' (and checking the examples, in formal/academic writing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way of saying this is to use the word [**variant**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/variant):

> **1** : manifesting variety, deviation, or disagreement
>   **2** : varying usually slightly from the standard form
>   // *variant* readings
>   // *variant* spellings

So, in your case, you would say:

> Dataset A is more *variant* than dataset B.

---

Generally, a comparison needs to be made to something else. So, in this case, dataset A is more variant than dataset B when it comes to some statistical norm.

For a more explicit statement, you could say something like this:

> In comparison to the norm, dataset A is more variant than dataset B.

---

If you're talking about the elements *within* a dataset, then you are comparing them to each other. In that case, you could use *variance* if you rephrased your sentence slightly:

> The elements of dataset A show more *variance* than those of dataset B.

Comment: To me, "more variant" does not mean "having a greater variance" in the statistical sense. Maybe it's just me, but that part of the answer seems wrong. "...show more variance" is good, though.

Comment: This sounds like it should be write but NGrams shows that it is hardly ever used in actual practice.

Answer (score 0):

`The dataset` cannot be `more variable` from my opinion. It just is. However `variance` is a property of the dataset, and it sounds OK in the very short example provided.

*Edit to improve after comment*: From my understanding, `the dataset` is a set of (let's say) numbers, acquired after some measurements (or any other activity). Therefore, the dataset cannot change (unless **new measurements** are done, leading to a **new dataset**). So the dataset cannot be `variable`. Let alone being `more variable`.

Comment: Thanks - the point is: From a statsitical point of view, "Variance" is an exactly quantifiable property. Therefore, a dataset can have a higher variance than another. I.e. if "variable" would be the correct choice of adjective, "more variable" should also make sense.

Comment: @user1934212: Thanks for pointing out incomplete answer :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out an incomplete question :-D See update.

Comment: You can _force_ a "simplification of language" and _ignore_ the comments from some guys like me. Only then `variable` can be used to describe something that does not change. :D But I may be wrong, you did not clarify if the dataset is fixed or volatile. The point is: if you need to use `variance`, you are not in the business to create romantic poems. Therefore, you should remain to the strict definition of words, without simplifications. My 2 cents ;)

Comment: On the other hand, whatever you use is your responsibility. So yes, go ahead and use anything :)

Comment: Logic may be on your side, but language isn't (always) logical. See the NGrams link in my comment on the OP.

Comment: @Mitch: language is how we make it :) You may be also right (I am not a statistics expert), but when we use words with different meanings than the widely used meaning - that is recipy for trouble. Why is it bad to use the unambiguous "variance" in a scientific paper? Why is it better to use words with multiple meanings?

Answer (score 0):

> Dataset A is more variable than dataset B.

**Yes,** this is perfectly good English. The only issue is whether *variable* is precise enough.

Variance is a very specific mathematical concept. If you want to say that the variance of A is greater than the variance of B, mathematically, I don't think there's an adjective that will do the job. Just use the noun:

> Dataset A has a higher variance than dataset B.

---

...or...

You can use *high-variance* as an adjective, as in “a high-variance dataset”. After seeing that a few times, readers will have no problem with sentences like:

> Dataset A is higher variance than dataset B.
>
> With higher-variance datasets, it is important to check that the results are significant.

This is a bit jargony, though. I think “has a higher variance” is better.